# Get subcollection with rules on the parent collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Firestore rule for a collection:

```js
match /mycollection/{documents=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author
  allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author
}
```

Basically to access `mycollection`, `author` must be equal to `uid`. This is working fine, where I can query this collection via react using:

```js
import { collection, where, query, orderBy } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useCollection } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

...
const [col, loading, error] = useCollection(
  query(collection(db, "mycollection"), where("author", "==", uid), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"))
)
...
```

Now I want to access a sub-collection but cannot do it:

```js
const [collection, loading, error] = useCollection(
  query(collection(db, `mycollection/${id}/subcollection`), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"))
)
```

I get the `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` error. Looks like I can't get to the subcollection without authenticating the parent collection, which is fine. But how do I pass the where condition to parent collection in the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@alex-mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) for the direction. However I might have found a solution that works better for me.

```
match /mycollection/{colId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author
  allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author
  
  match /subcollection/{subColId} {
    allow read, write, create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/mycollection/$(colId)).data.author
  }
}
```

This rule gets author value from the parent document and compares it with current user's uid. If they are equal, the user has access to the sub-collection.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for the top-level collections do not apply to sub-collections unless you are using a recursive wildcard. If you have different rules for the collection and sub-collection, then you have to explicitly define them for the collection and sub-collections. So to solve this, you can nest the sub-collections rules in the collection itself. So your rules should look like this:

```
match /mycollection/{documents=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author
  allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author

    match /subcollection/ {
      //Your rules
    }
}
```

However, if the rules are the same, you can use a recursive wildcard:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in the mycollection collection as well as any document in a subcollection.
    match /mycollection/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

Please also see below, a link that explains how to use hierarchical data:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data

Comment: How does the authentication work? Does the subcollection also need the author field?

Comment: Also how does the client query look like? Couldn't find anything in the docs for nested where queries.

Comment: I intentionally did not add any rules, because I don't know exactly what would like to allow and what not. It's up to you to decide what the rules should reject and what not.

Comment: I understand. But the sub-collection doesn't have rules on its own, just that it should be accessible if the user has access to the parent collection.

Comment: If you want a user to be able to access a top-level collection as well as a sub-collection, you should write rules for that. I have also edited my question and added the link to the docs where it is explained in detail how to use hierarchical data.

Comment: Thank you. One last question, on the client side, how do I query it? Because the parent collection would also need a where clause right? Otherwise you cannot traverse to the sub-collection node? How do I provide where clause to the parent as well to the sub-collection? Because with this `query(collection(db, 'mycollection/${id}/subcollection'), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"))`, if I add the where clause it would only apply to the sub-collection right?

Comment: You cannot query a  sub-collection based on what exists in the parent collection. Queries in Firestore are shallow, they only return documents from the collection the query is run against. So you have to perform two queries or duplicate the data so it can return everything you need in a single query.

Comment: Actually I might have found a better solution for me. I have added it as an answer. What do you think?